# Where can I go to study how to make smart contracts

Tags: smart-contracts

In particular, I have an idea, I want to create a contract to delegate Tezos to a designated baker, but in a more long term contract, where he can use my delegation as bond, however if he double bakes he still takes the initial risk.  Or in the smart contract we can share the risk, but I am still in control of my Tezzies.  Or, I put half(for example) of my delegated Tezzies into a bond and the rest to him, but the whole amount( say 150 in bond, 150 delegated, for 300 total, times 9-ish makes about 2700 extra bond so he can have extra delegators).  How would I go about researching how to do this?

Comment: Programmable baking is something that Adrian Brink has discussed at the recent TQuorum in NYC. I invite you to have a look at it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntsvD4mw8yE It covers what you want to do and more. Alas, no time frame on implementation and a similar proposal called Burebrot was met with great protests from the community and the simple mention of this was enough for the protestors to come back out of the woodwork: https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/djzvoz/cryptium_labs_is_planning_burebrot_20/  Personally, I'd welcome it.

Answer (score 2):

The first place to go will always be the main Tezos developer portal found at https://developers.tezos.com/

From there you primarily need to determine which smart contract language best fits with your team's skillset. There are always new languages and tools being created to support a broader ecosystem of devs.

Follow the tutorials and examples in the language and tools that you choose, ask specific questions here on the Tezos stackexchange and join the dev channels for the tools you've chosen.